# Detect user logged on a computer using ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, windows-authentication

I want to develop an ASP.NET application that can detect the user logged on a Window Domain. These credentials  are going to be used to logging on the ASP.NET application.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In IIS, turn on Integrated Windows Authentication, and in code, if you use:

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

it will return the windows username of the logged in user, i.e. MYDOMAIN\MYUSERNAME

Comment: If the user does anonymous logon on IIS I can't see his data. This only works on the computer where IIS is running.

Answer (score 1):

Here is C# code I use to authenticate against the Active Directory

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace XYZcompany.Enterprise
{
  public class AuthenicationMgr
  {
    private static readonly int AD_ERR_LOGON_FAIL = -2147023570;
    private static readonly string _path = "LDAP://xxx.yyy.ggg";
    private static readonly string _domain = "xxx.yyy.ggg";

    public static bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string pwd)
    {
      bool authenticatedFlag = true;
      string domainAndUsername = _domain + "\\" + username;
      DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);
      try
      {
        // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
        Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

        if (result == null)
        {
          authenticatedFlag = false;
        }
        else
        {
          authenticatedFlag = true;
        }
      }
      catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
      {
        if (ex.ErrorCode == AD_ERR_LOGON_FAIL)
        {
          authenticatedFlag = false;
        }
        else
        {
          throw new ApplicationException("Unable to authenticate user due to system error.", ex);
        }
      }
      return authenticatedFlag;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't ask this but I will need it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.net, you can probably use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

If IIS is configured correctly (no anonymous logons, at least)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the active directory membership provider.  It's built into ASP.NET.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.ToString
```

Comment: This won't work with ASP.NET applications, since this will return the credentials of IIS, not the logged in user

Comment: I use this everyday, and it works fine for me, and all the users using the website.

Comment: Then you're probably using identity impersonation, which horrible and not recommended.