# Tomcat and windows integrated authentication

Tags: tomcat, windows-authentication

I'm developing a Java app that must run on Tomcat and I need to be able to identify the remote user who is acceding to my application web.

This remote user is running on Windows, so I need to get his "Windows login" (the SAMAccountName Active Directory attribute).

On IIS is easiest. I follow this [Detect user logged on a computer using ASP.NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688939/detect-user-logged-on-a-computer-using-asp-net-app) to get the user logged

The content of server.xml is:

```
<Realm
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="99"
    connectionURL="ldap://DAServer:389"
    connectionName="userAuth@mydomain.local"
    connectionPassword="secret"
    referrals="follow"
    userBase="OU=mycompany,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
    userSubtree="true"
    roleBase="OU=groups,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
    roleName="name"
    roleSubtree="true"
    roleSearch="(member={0})"/>
```

And the content of web.xml is:

```
<!-- Define a Security Constraint on this Application -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>myCompany Users</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Define the Login Configuration for this Application -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>

    <!-- Security roles referenced by this web application -->
    <security-role>
        <description>The role that is required to log in to APP</description>
        <role-name>myCompany Users</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

I need Automatic Login.

Comment: OP's accepted answer is a link to a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If you are building an Intranet application and are looking for SSO then you can use something like [Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html) which is based on [jCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/).

Comment: Maybe I don't need a new library, I only need to integrate windows authentication like IIS does.

Comment: Jespa is NOT based on JCIFS. The JCIFS NTLM HTTP filter is flawed in a number of ways so it is very unfortunate to characterize Jespa in this way. Jespa just uses JCIFS for it's MS-RPC layer and some basic NTLM computations. But the API and functionality bare no resemblance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the Tomcat JNDI realm and integrate it with your server's active directory

Try [here](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/ActiveDirectoryIntegration) for some guidelines

Comment: I added more details about my problem